# Stop exceptions from bring up implementation in visual studio 2019

Tags: c++, visual-studio

When debugging my program sometimes it will break with an exception and bring up the c++ implementation which makes it difficult to figure out where the bug is occurring. Currently I have to manually go through step by step to figure out which exact line is causing the program to break, which can be tedious or impossible if there are complex loops involved. Is there a setting I can check to break inside only files that I have written in or inside a cetin filter to avoid going to the external dependencies filter?

Comment: Have you seen the "call stack" panel?

Comment: I thought [`JustMyCode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019) was enabled by default these days. Edit: oh I guess this part specifically is what's annoying to you "If the debugger hits an exception, it stops on the exception, whether it is in user or non-user code. User-unhandled options in the Exception Settings dialog box are ignored."

Comment: Use the "Stack Frame" combo box on the debug toolbar

Comment: I find that if you use third party libraries JustMyCode does not help much.

Comment: @user253751 Looking at it right now, might be what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just My Code is for this, and enabled by default for most languages.

To enable Just My Code in Visual Studio follow these steps :

```
under Tools > Options (or Debug > Options) > Debugging > General
```

select Enable Just My Code.

[image]